# On iOS 15 only, when I run the application I get the error: dyld[6062]: Symbol not found: (_swift_getExtendedExistentialTypeMetadata)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile

I have a real problem with an app in production that doesn't work with iOS 15.
Symptom: When I launch the app, I get a blank screen for a second and then the app kills.
The only info from Xcode after the crash is the following:

Build real device run release :

```
dyld[6062]: Symbol not found: (_swift_getExtendedExistentialTypeMetadata)
  Referenced from: '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/661DFEBF-EA64-489A-9DA3-3957077A0C3A/yummypets.app/yummypets'
  Expected in: '/usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib'
```

Setup :
Xcode 14.3.1
Swift 5.8.1
Swift language version in Xcode : 5
Minimum deployment : iOS 15
Zero error message for incompatibility

I've already tried a few things, including :

- Cleaning & rebuilding
- Runpath Search Paths is $(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks
- Embedded Content Contains Swift Code is 'Yes
- Signing Identity is developer
- Rollback to previous version
- delete Xcode
- check packages
  I managed to avoid the first crash by adding "-Wl,-weak-lswiftCore" to other linking flag in Build Settings, but it's not ideal and leads to other problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are running into the same issue as https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/64657

From what I understand, that casts the generic constraints of the type `any Blah<Something>`, the Swift compiler emits an object file that depends on the `swift_getExtendedExistentialTypeMetadata` function, which is not present before iOS 16 runtime.

My approach to resolving it:

Use a disassembler like https://ghidra-sre.org/ to find references to the symbol `_swift_getExtendedExistentialTypeMetadata`. You'll have a cast (as/as?) or is in the function which would be the culprit.

If someone can come up with a smarter script using objdump I'll welcome it :)